# Fetch multiple pages of json with jq

Tags: json, bash, terminal, jq

When calling an API, I am returned a json that can be pretty printed with

```
curl "https://mywebsite.com/api/cars.json&page=1" |  jq '.'
```

Below is a sample output.  Seeing as there are two pages of records (112 total entries and only 100 entries showing per page), what command can I use in `jq` to immediately fetch both pages of data?

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "per_page": 100,
  "total_entries": 112,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "vehicleA",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 100
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 75
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 50
    }...
```

Comment: You can't; `jq` doesn't know anything about HTTP. `curl` fetches the data; `jq` just processes the output of `curl`.

Comment: Have you checked the API to see if there's isn't some way to request more than a single page?  Or maybe you can avoid pagination altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jq` doesn't fetch pages. You need to fetch pages with multiple `curl` calls, and then combine the JSON outputs.
For example you could get a JSON array of the combined `.item` properties:

```
url=https://mywebsite.com/api/cars.json
jq -s '.[0].items + .[1].items' <(curl "$url&page=1" | jq .) <(curl "$url&page=2" | jq .)
```

If you don't know in advance the number of pages you'll need,
then you'll need to work a bit harder, but it's of course possible.

Get the total entries from the first page:

```
total=$(curl "$url&page=1" | jq .total_entries)
```

Compute the number of pages:

```
((pages = total / 100))

if ((total % 100 > 0)); then
    ((pages++))
else
```

And then you can write a loop to download the results page by page,
generate the `jq` command `.[0].items + ... + .[n].items` and call `jq` with it to get the combined JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can download all of the pages and create an array of all of the entries (much like @janos answer above), then you need not computationally generate the `jq` command.  Instead you can use `flatten` as in
`jq '[.[].items] | flatten'`